# Fetching the innerHTML from TD in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-side

Hi I am using Sharepoint 2010 page, where I have the HTML snipet with the following structure:

```
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td class="ms-vb2"></td>
  <td class="ms-vb2"></td>
  <td class="ms-vb2"></td>
  <td class="ms-vb2"></td>
  <td class="ms-vb2"><nobr><b>Sum= 72</b></nobr></td>
  <td class="ms-vb2"><nobr><b>Sum= 66</b></nobr></td>
</tr>
```

Now I want to get the value 72 and 66 from the TD tag in a var, so that I can use these values in the client scripts.

The "Sum=" part of the TD is not supposed to change. And the ID of the table is randomly generated by sharepoint so I can't do anything with that as well.

Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution- took time for me to generate the same.. :)

```
 var arrValue = "";
    $('td.ms-vb2').filter(function (i) {
        if ($(this).html().indexOf('Sum=') > 0) {

            mystring = $(this).html();
            var result = /\d+(?:\.\d+)?/.exec(mystring);
            //console.log(arrValue)
            arrValue = result[0] + "," + arrValue
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ms-vb2 b").each(function(td) {
   var s = td.hmtl().replace("Sum= ", "");
    $("body").append(s);
});
```

Here's [the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/dsr6T/).

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you..

**Fiddle :**  http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/150/

```
$('td.ms-vb2').each(function() {    
    var value = $(this).text();
    if(value !="")
     alert(value);
    //If you want to replace the Sum= in Text then try the below code
    $(this).text($(this).text().replace("Sum= ",""));
});
```